# Combine Layout files for multiple version numbers

Tags: android, layout

All I have a different layout files for different versions of android like  `layout-v13` ,  but I noticed that the files are the same for newer versions of android (API 11-16). Is there a way to group them together as something like `layout-v11,12,13,14,15,16`? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`layout-v11` will be used by all devices running Android 3.0 and above. You should only break up the folders (i.e. `layout-v11`, `layout-v12`, etc.) if devices running the specific version require a different layout.

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: As mentioned i have a layout file in v11 placed but API 23 ignores it. When i create a copy and place it in v17 it works as expected. So from v11 to v16 it is fully ignored. This doesn't happen on API 15 for example. Seems a platform specific bug.

Answer (score 4):

If what you're trying to do is show a different layout depending on which API version is available on the device, you want to use [configuration qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers). The specifics for alternative resources are also [documented](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

The most basic way to do it is to create a layout folder for each API level you want to use, formatted as follows:

```
res/layout/layout.xml       (Default)
res/layout-v4/layout.xml    (Android 1.6 and higher)
res/layout-v11/layout.xml   (Android 3.0 and higher)
```

From Android  official documentation
[image]

In your case `layout-v11` this will be used by devices running Android 3.0 Honeycomb and above

Comment: I have a layout created in `layout-v11` but it is ignored on v23.